# Do map stamps take inventory space?

Tags: team-fortress-2

If I were to purchase the Map Stamps Collection, would I need *eighteen* inventory slots?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Map Stamps do not take up any inventory space.  However, the first time you buy a map stamp, you receive the [World Traveler's Hat](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/World_Traveler%27s_Hat).

The World Traveler's Hat will have a falling stamp particle effect on any map you own a stamp for.

Note that only user contributed maps that are now shipped with the game have stamps, of which there are (as of 2011/11/17) 18: Turbine, Egypt, Fastlane, Steel, Watchtower, Harvest, Junction, Mountain Lab, Mann Manor, Yukon, Freight, Hoodoo, Offblast, Coldfront, Frontier, Lakeside, Nightfall, Gullywash.

Your hat also has ranks based on the number of stamps you own for a specific map.  This rank changes for every 25 stamps you own for a map up until 200.  Again, these are tracked separately for each map.

Answer (score 10):

No.  Map stamps and not stored in the backpack.  They're attached to your hat but will not use up a slot.